# How can I mount a volume of files to a remote docker daemon?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a Docker image `a` which does some logic on a given set of files. When running locally, I start `a` as following:

```
docker run -v /home/Bradson/data:/data a
```

This does its job.

Now I want to run `a` on a remote Docker daemon:

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://remote_host:2375 docker run -v /home/Bradson/data:/data a
```

I am now getting the error that `/data` does not contain anything, most likely because `/home/Bradson/data` does not exist on the remote host.

How do I approach this? Should I first `scp` `/home/Bradson/data` to some directory on the remote host and refer to that director in the `-v` option? Is there a pure Docker approach?

Please note that I want to make `/home/Bradson/data` available at runtime, not during the build of `a`. Hence my usage of the `-v` option.

Comment: This answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55683656/1315009 fits your question, although the question is not an exact duplicate. The other question asks for a "generic" copy while the particular answer of the triad `create`+`cp`+`rm` does effectively work with remote volumes, which was your concern (and mine).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is an answer to my own question.

I found the following pure Docker approach. I was looking for a way to copy files to a volume directly, but that does not seem to be supported for some reason?

You can copy files to a container however. So the following works:

```
 export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://remote_host:2375
 docker volume create data-volume
 docker create -v data-volume:/data --name helper busybox true
 docker cp /home/Bradson/data helper:/data
 docker rm helper
 docker run -v data-volume:/data a
```

This is inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/37469637/10042924.

Comment: im also looking for a solution to this issue. one that makes the local directory to the remote host right from docker-compose where you set the volume to /home/dev:/remote/dev

Comment: Better link https://stackoverflow.com/a/55683656/1315009 => The "next" answer to the one you are linking.